# Why is Fabric in AWSCore

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

Why is Fabric in AWSCore? Not talking about hyperledger fabric.

See: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSCore/Fabric

Answer (score 0):

It exists to provide support/ integration with Amazon Cognito.

Comment: What sort of support?